# Mongoose JS subdocument unique validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm building an application that uses mobile device UID's as one of the means to authenticate sessions per parent model. My intention being a user can be authenticated to multiple parents but only have one session entry in the database per parent.

```
ParentSchema {
  sessions: [{
   device_uid: { type: String, unique: true }
  }]
}
```

Session is it's own schema object (written inline for simplicity sake).

My question is: If I put the unique validation on the device_uid, is the context of the validation the subdocuments for IT'S parent or ALL session subdocuments for ALL parents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique index on `device_uid` within the sub-doc of the `sessions` array ensures that no two documents can have a `sessions` array element with the same `device_uid`.  It does, however, [still allow](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#behavior) two elements within the *same* document to have the same `device_uid`.

Comment: Interesting. So even though the subdocument is it's own schema, the unique validation is still in context of the top most parent schema or document?

Comment: @snowman4415 Correct. The Mongoose indexes are always implemented using a MongoDB index defined on the collection.